# Not able run Virtual Host on Docker Container using Laravel Sail on MAC OS

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have setup `Laravel 8` on my `Mac OS`. I am using `Laravel Sail` to setup `Docker container`.

My application works proper on **`http://localhost:8081`**. However, I want to make
**`admin.website-dev.com`** to work.

Here is the **`docker-compose.yml`**

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        container_name: 'bv_laravel_http'
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '8081:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        container_name: 'bv_laravelreact_mysql'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3360}:3360'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6378}:6378'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7701}:7701'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1024}:1024'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8026}:8026'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Here is the **`/etc/hosts`**

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       laravel.test
127.0.0.1 admin.website-dev.com
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you see when you point your browser to http://admin.website-dev.com:8081 ?

Comment: @jabbson Its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I see that the issue was confirmed to be related to not including the port when pointing the browser to the application in the docker by locally configured domain name.

Using

```
admin.website-dev.com:8081
```

instead of

```
admin.website-dev.com
```

seems to have fixed the issue.